# How can I solve this Intel Management Engine Interface driver error?

Tags: drivers, motherboard

I have a [Gigabyte GA-P55-US3L rev 2.0 mainboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3347&dl=1#ov). After my Windows 7 64-bit installation I tried to install all the drivers from Gigabyte's site but I can't install the Intel Management Engine Interface driver.

It gives me this error:

> This computer does not meet minimum requirements for installing the software.

I don't know what to do. I've searched the net but couldn't find anything. My system configuration is as follows:

```
CPU    INTEL Core i5-750 SLBLC, 2.66GHz, 8MB L3, çift kanal DDR3, LGA1156

Memmory 2 x GSKILL F3-10666CL7D-4GBRH G.SKILL Ripjaws DDR3-1333Mhz CL7 4GB (2x2GB) DUAL (7-7-7-21) 1.5V

HDD SAMSUNG HD502HJ Spinpoint F3 500GB 16MB 7200rpm NCQ SATA 3.0Gb/s

GPU -  POWERCOLOR AX5850 1GBD5-PPDHG HD5850 PCS+, PCI-E16 2.1, 1GB/256bit GDDR5, HDMI, 2xDVI, DisplayPort (Dirt2)

Combo RW SAMSUNG SH-S223C 22X Siyah, Kutusuz

Memory- GSKILL F3-10666CL7D-4GBRH G.SKILL Ripjaws DDR3-1333Mhz CL7 4GB (2x2GB) DUAL (7-7-7-21) 1.5V

SSD - Corsair Force GT 120 GB - SATA 3
```

Any thoughts how to get it to install?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you downloaded the 32-bit installer by accident, or perhaps your particular motherboard doesn't contain the IME hardware component?

Comment: No i downloaded the only installer for my motherboard. It contains both 32-bit and 64-bit. If it doesn't have IME hardware component why do they provide that driver :S

Comment: Did you install the "Intel INF" first? Try that, then retry the IME driver.

Comment: Yes of course , i did. One more time i tried to update INF and IME. Inf successfully updated but IME says my computer doesn't meet minimum requirements again :(