# Cannot update the Intel Management Engine Interface Driver for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have gone through this [Post](https://superuser.com/questions/524996/how-can-i-solve-intel-management-engine-interface-driver-error) before asking a new one but didn't solve my problem.So i am asking it here.

By this [site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/8TG7NP1/drivers?&DCP=Email&s=DHS) I performed a system analysis to check for any updates with drivers and got the Intel Management Engine Interface Driver had to be updated.

So I download the file later it unzips it to particular destination folder and the Setup starts.But midway the process stops and i receive a Fie Copying was not successful.Setup will exit pop up window .As there is no other option so i press the OK and set up terminates abruptly

[image]

Now what do i need to do so that i can complete the update process successfuly.

Comment: Did you try downloading the installer again (in case it's corrupted in some way)?  Have you checked your disk for free space and/or errors? Have you tried uninstalling the old Intel ME driver rebooting and then trying to install the new version?

Comment: Have you rebooted to get a clean system, and then try.  Another thing that I might try reboot, uninstall the old, reboot then try to install again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have downloaded the driver twice.After the first install if the instal was no completed then i did a restart and later re-tried with the second file and got the same issue

Comment: See if you can get to that file-path. Open "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel (R) Management Engine Components\LMS\LMS ..." and try to add a .txt to it or something. See if you have permissions to make changes to that folder. If the folder doesn't exit, try to create it. It may be that for some reason down that rabbit-hole your permissions are messed up, not allowing the program to make changes to one or more folders in that location.